# Os dados inteiros dentro do dropdown carregam na requisição get e no post não

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Fiz uma função edit que trabalha com 3 models diferentes, o get carrega os dados do id que eu selecionei, mas na hora do post, os inteiros dentro dos dropdowns vem com o atributo 0.

Segue meu código para avaliação:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditarFuncionario(string id) {

    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(MyCrypto.Decrypt(id));

    var vm = new FuncionarioVm();
    var vmTel = new TelefoneVm();
    var vmEnd = new EnderecoVm();

    var func = db.Funcionarios.Find(Id);
    var tel = db.Telefones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AssociadoId == Id);
    var end = db.Enderecos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AssociadoId == Id);

    vm.CarregarVm(func);
    vmTel.CarregarTelVm(tel);
    vmEnd.CarregarEndVm(end);

    ViewData["Funcionarios"] = vm;
    ViewData["Telefones"] = vmTel;
    ViewData["Enderecos"] = vmEnd;


    ConfigurarViewBagVm(vm, vmTel, vmEnd);

    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditarFuncionario(FuncionarioVm item1, TelefoneVm item2, EnderecoVm item3) {

    ConfigurarViewBagVm(item1, item2, item3);

    try {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {

            //AlterarFuncionario(item1, item2, item3);
            var func = new Funcionario();
            func.AssociadoId = item1.AssociadoId;
            func.Email = item1.Email;
            func.ClassificacaoId = item1.ClassificacaoId;
            func.Nome = item1.Nome;
            func.Rg = item1.Rg;
            func.Cpf = item1.Cpf;
            func.SexoId = item1.SexoId;
            func.DataNascimento = item1.DataNascimento;
            func.NroCtps = item1.NumeroCTPS;
            func.SerieCtps = item1.SerieCTPS;
            func.NroPis = item1.NumeroPis;
            func.DataContratacao = item1.DataContratacao;
            func.CargoId = item1.CargoId;
            func.ContaBancaria = item1.ContaBancaria;
            func.ContaBancariaId = item1.ContaBancariaId;
            func.GroupId = item1.GroupId;
            db.Entry(func).State = EntityState.Modified;

            var tel = new Telefone();
            tel.Ddd = item2.Ddd;
            tel.Numero = item2.NumeroTelefone;
            tel.TipoTelefoneId = item2.TipoTelefoneId;
            db.Entry(tel).State = EntityState.Modified;

            var end = new Endereco();
            end.Rua = item3.Rua;
            end.Bairro = item3.Bairro;
            end.Numero = item3.Numero;
            end.Cep = item3.Cep;
            end.Complemento = item3.Complemento;
            end.TipoEndereco = item3.TipoEndereco;
            end.TipoEnderecoId = item3.TipoEnderecoId;
            end.Cidade = item3.Cidade;
            end.CidadeId = item3.CidadeId;
            db.Entry(end).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Mensagem = "Alterado com sucesso!";
        }
    } catch (Exception) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Erro");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ManterFuncionario");
}
```

Função que configura os dropdowns:

```
private void ConfigurarViewBagVm(FuncionarioVm vm, TelefoneVm vmTel, EnderecoVm vmE) {
        ViewBag.SexoId = db.Sexos.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nome, Value = item.SexoId.ToString(), Selected = item.SexoId == vm.SexoId }).OrderBy(item => item.Text).ToList();
        ViewBag.CargoId = db.Cargos.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nome, Value = item.CargoId.ToString(), Selected = item.CargoId == vm.CargoId }).OrderBy(item => item.Text).ToList();
        ViewBag.ClassificacaoId = db.Classificacoes.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nome, Value = item.ClassificacaoId.ToString(), Selected = item.ClassificacaoId == vm.ClassificacaoId }).OrderBy(item => item.Text).ToList();
        ViewBag.BancoId = db.Bancos.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nome, Value = item.BancoId.ToString(), Selected = item.BancoId == vm.BancoId }).OrderBy(item => item.Text).ToList();
        ViewBag.GroupId = db.Groups.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.GroupName, Value = item.GroupId.ToString(), Selected = item.GroupId == vm.GroupId }).OrderBy(item => item.Text).ToList();
        ViewBag.TipoContaId = db.TipoContas.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Tipo, Value = item.TipoContaId.ToString(), Selected = item.TipoContaId == vm.TipoContaId }).OrderBy(item => item.Text).ToList();

        ViewBag.TipoTelefoneId = db.TipoTelefones.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Tipo, Value = item.TipoTelefoneId.ToString(), Selected = item.TipoTelefoneId == vm.TipoTelefoneId }).OrderBy(item => item.Text).ToList();

        ViewBag.CidadeId = db.Cidades.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nome, Value = item.CidadeId.ToString(), Selected = item.CidadeId == vmE.CidadeId }).OrderBy(item => item.Text).ToList();
        ViewBag.TipoEnderecoId = db.TipoEnderecos.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Tipo, Value = item.TipoEnderecoId.ToString(), Selected = item.TipoEnderecoId == vmE.TipoEnderecoId }).OrderBy(item => item.Text).ToList();

        ViewBag.EstadoId = db.Estados.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nome, Value = item.EstadoId.ToString(), Selected = item.EstadoId == vmE.EstadoId }).OrderBy(item => item).ToList();

    }

@using DigitalFashion.Models.Pessoas
@using DigitalFashion.Util

@{ 
    FuncionarioVm Item1 = ViewData["Funcionarios"] as FuncionarioVm;
    TelefoneVm Item2 = ViewData["Telefones"] as TelefoneVm;
    EnderecoVm Item3 = ViewData["Enderecos"] as EnderecoVm;

}


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditarFuncionario";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditarFuncionario", "Pessoa", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Item1.AssociadoId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Item2.AssociadoId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Item3.AssociadoId)

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>Editando os dados do funcionário: @Item1.Nome</h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="~/Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/Home">Pessoas</a></li>
                <li class="active"> Editando funcionário</li>
            </ol>
        </section>
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="container cadastro-cliente">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <!-- CONTENT FIRST TAB -->
                    <div class="tab-content cadastro-cliente" id="nav-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-dados-pessoais" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-dados-pessoais-tab">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item1.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.Usuario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item1.Usuario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.Usuario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.Senha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item1.Senha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.Senha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.Rg, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Item1.Rg, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.Rg, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.Cpf, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Item1.Cpf, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.Cpf, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Item1.DataNascimento, "dd/MM/yyyy", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" })                                       
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.DataContratacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Item1.DataContratacao, "dd/MM/yyyy", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.DataContratacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.SexoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("SexoId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Item1.SexoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.CargoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("CargoId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Item1.CargoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item1.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.NumeroPis, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item1.NumeroPis, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.NumeroPis, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.NumeroCTPS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Item1.NumeroCTPS, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.NumeroCTPS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.SerieCTPS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Item1.SerieCTPS, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.SerieCTPS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item2.Ddd, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Item2.Ddd, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item2.Ddd, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item2.NumeroTelefone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Item2.NumeroTelefone, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item2.NumeroTelefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item2.TipoTelefoneId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("TipoTelefoneId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Item2.TipoTelefoneId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item3.Rua, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item3.Rua, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item3.Rua, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item3.Numero, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item3.Numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item3.Numero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item3.Bairro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item3.Bairro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item3.Bairro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item3.Complemento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item3.Complemento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item3.Complemento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item3.Cep, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item3.Cep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item3.Cep, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item3.TipoEnderecoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("TipoEnderecoId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Item3.TipoEnderecoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item3.CidadeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("CidadeId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Item3.CidadeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => Item3.EstadoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            @Html.DropDownList("EstadoId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Item3.EstadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.ClassificacaoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("ClassificacaoId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Item1.ClassificacaoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.ContaBancaria.Numero, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item1.ContaBancaria.Numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.ContaBancaria.Numero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.ContaBancaria.Agencia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Item1.ContaBancaria.Agencia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Item1.ContaBancaria.Agencia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.BancoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("BancoId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Item1.BancoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Item1.TipoContaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("TipoContaId", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Item1.TipoContaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <p>
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Editar Cliente" class="btn btn-success btn-cadastra-cliente" />
                                    </div>
                                </p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Já tentei alterar meu código de todas as formas, mas simplesmente não consigo passar desta etapa.

Comment: Seria interessante você agrupar essas suas três viewmodels em uma única que possui as possui as três.

Comment: A falta de agrupamento das vms pode ser o problema? Tive algumas complicações em agrupá-las, mas vou tentar desta forma que você me sugeriu

Comment: Outro detalhe é a bagunça que você está fazendo com ViewModel, ViewBag e ViewData.

Comment: Que bagunça? Poderia me dar algumas dicas de como escrever um código mais limpo? Estou utilizando a viewbag para fazer a configuração do meu dropdown ea ViewData para carregar os dados de outras models em uma View, anteriormente estava utilizando tuplas para fazer este carregamento, mas alterei para ViewData por questão de estética

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse artigo. https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/viewmodel-viewdata-viewbag-tempdata-mvc